# Check if session has expired in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

In my current project, I have implemented revisionable, which keeps a track of all the revisions that are made in the application.

The problem happening is when the session expires, and user makes a revision, this revision is stored in DB. But, instead, there should be a message that displays that "Session has expired" or it should redirect to the login page.

How can I implement this so that it applies to my entire application in one go?

Comment: a simple google search gave me this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/keep-getting-tokenmismatchexception-verifycsrftokenphp-on-line-46?page=2

Comment: @SarmenB. Its not about the TokenMismatchException, I think

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
if ((time() - Session::activity()) > (Config::get('session.lifetime') * 60))
{
   // Session expired
}
```

**Edit 01**

```
class MyController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct()
    {
        if ((time() - Session::activity()) > (Config::get('session.lifetime') * 60))
        {
            // Session expired
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Should I make a Middleware for this?

Comment: You can use as it is.

Comment: But where do I use it?

Comment: Where you need to check session, Better to include in all conterollers

Comment: I need to check it in every controller. What would be a better way to do it?

Comment: use that in `__construct()`

Comment: So every controllers constructor will have this?

Comment: or you can call that in model. Choice is up to you

Comment: i dnt know much about laravel. I just no code, @phantomphoenix

Comment: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Session\Store' does not have a method 'activity'

Gives me this error.

Comment: simply use `if(Session::has('your_key')){ your code }else{ another code}` @phantomphoenix